# Firestore select query to change structure of data returned

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firebase Firestore to build a web-based app (JavaScript). But I've come to a problem with the way my data is currently structured for what I want to do.

I have a the following data model:

```
{
sources: [
     name: '',
     uid: '1234567890'
     ]
,
accounts: [
     name: '',
     uid: '1234567890'
     ]
}
```

I would like to make a query that can allow me to structure the data back to the browser like so:

```
{
sources: [
     name: '',
     uid: '1234567890',
     accounts: [
          name: '',
          uid: '1234567890'
          ]
     ]
}
```

Obviously with `uid`'s matching. There will not be a lot of data overall if that matters. Maybe 1-4 sources, and 4-8 accounts. Any help would be great! Not sure if I need to chain promises together to put it all together (my guess) or if there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing called a "join" in SQL terms.  Firestore doesn't support joins, in order to be able to scale massively.  With your current structure, you have to read each document individually and combine the results on the client.  Alternatively, you can store another document with pre-joined data from multiple collections, which is called denormalization.  Denormalization is common in NoSQL type databases that don't support joins.

Comment: Ok, I can put them together on the client end. I was really hoping Firestore had a trick up their sleeve for this common scenario.

Comment: The trick is to *not* support these kinds of queries, as they cause issues as massive scale.  As with all things, there is a tradeoff between scalability and flexibility.  You might want to read this to learn about other limits and how to work around them: https://medium.com/firebase-developers/the-top-10-things-to-know-about-firestore-when-choosing-a-database-for-your-app-a3b71b80d979